# Troubleshooting JSON retrieval issue with WordPress API plugin. Using Nextjs, wordpress api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, next.js

I am attempting to retrieve JSON data from a WordPress API using a plugin. However, when I attempt to log the data, I am not receiving the JSON and am unsure of what may be causing the issue.

After doing more research, I think it's because of the following.
Next.js uses the App component to initialize pages. You can override it and control the page initialization. To achieve that simply create `_app.js` file in root of pages directory. For more information follow this link: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

but i am not sure what is means and how to fix this

```
import Header from '@/components/layouts/header';
import { HEADER_FOOTER_ENDPOINT } from '../utils/constants/endpoints';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../styles/index.scss';

export default function Home({data}) {
  console.log(HEADER_FOOTER_ENDPOINT); // shows working api (https://there2compare.com/wp-json/rae/v1/header-footer?header_location_id=hcms-menu-header&footer_location_id=hcms-menu-footer)
  console.log('props', data); // props undefined
 
  return (
     <Header/>
  ) 
}


export async function getStaticProps() {
  const {data} = await axios.get(HEADER_FOOTER_ENDPOINT);
return {
      props: {
          data: data || {},
      },
      /**
         * Revalidate means that if a new request comes to server, then every 1 sec it will check
         * if the data is changed, if it is changed then it will update the
         * static file inside .next folder with the new data, so that any 'SUBSEQUENT' requests should have updated data.
         */
      revalidate: 1,
  };
}
```